# TableView refresh issue after core data deleted

Tags: swift, tableview

I am using Core Data to store inputs from a first VC. In a 2nd VC I added a tableView showing all data entered by the user and it works well. In this same VC I have a delete all data button that effectively deletes my complete Core Data database and added ->
tableView.reloadData() in the action of my button after the deletion of all my objects. 
My tableView doesn't update correctly even by going back and forth between both VCs. In ViewDidLoad I also added the tableView.reloadData() but nothing changes. The tableView refresh is working in one unique case if I close my app and relaunch it. Any clue on what I missed?

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DisplayViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var deleteDay: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var deleteAll: UIButton!

    var dateOfInputs = [DateOfInputs]()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func deleteAllDatabase(_ sender: Any) {

        //getting context from your Core Data Manager Class

        if DateOfInputs.clearAll() {
            dateOfInputs = DateOfInputs.fetchObject()!
            print ("Clear All")
        }

        try? AppDelegate.viewContext.save()

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    var datas = DateOfInputs.all
    var dateStringArray : [String] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        deleteDay.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        deleteDay.layer.borderWidth = 3
        deleteAll.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        deleteAll.layer.borderWidth = 3

       // navigationItem.title = "My Own Data"
       // navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        datas = DateOfInputs.all

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension DisplayViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return datas.count // one row for the input levels and one for comment
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! DisplayVCTableviewCell

       let data = datas[indexPath.row]

     // converting my dates to strings

       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM, yyyy"
       let newDate = dateFormatter.string(from: data.date!)

       cell.myDate.text = (newDate)
       cell.myValues.text = " Sleep: \(data.sleepVal)  Stom.: \(data.stomachVal)  En.: \(data.energyVal)"
       cell.myComment.text = (data.comment)

       return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jimy, Could you share the code of the 2nd VC?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] to make the question on topic.

Answer (score 0):

Reload TableView is not enough. You need to grab your object with NSFetchRequest.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Device"];
self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, xNinjaSwift, I did a fetchObject -> below the 2nd VC code:

Comment: before reload in viewDidAppear do fetchrequest. Maybe your model is wrong and it cant fetch date, cos there are no data. Did you use nsset?

Comment: My fetch request looks to work otherwise I wouldn't see it initially in my tables as all entries are correctly showing in TableView. I added in the func deleteAllDatabase - a fetch request just after the context.save and before the tableview.reloadData but without success. I will try to add it on viewDidAppear as you mention but the logic is not clear for me. After deletion of all data in Core Data and saving the context it looks here the right place to do a fetchrequest at this place but as said it doesn't work.